# Traefik behind a layer 4 AWS legacy network load balancer -- how to add requestor IP address into access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, traefik

I am using Traefik inside of Kubernetes and there is an AWS layer 4 level legacy network load balancer in front. I am trying to add the original requestor ip address into the Traefik access logs, but I cannot get it working.

Here is the relevant Traefik configuration *(in Helm yaml format)*:

```
  proxyProtocol:
    enabled: true
    trustedIPs:
      - 192.168.0.0/16
      - 10.0.0.0/8
      - 172.16.0.0/12

  forwardedHeaders:
    enabled: true
    # trustedIPs is required when enabled
    trustedIPs:
      - 192.168.0.0/16
      - 10.0.0.0/8
      - 172.16.0.0/12
```

And here is the access logs configuration:

```
  accessLogs:
    enabled: true
    ## Path to the access logs file. If not provided, Traefik defaults it to stdout.
    # filePath: ""
    format: common  # choices are: common, json
    ## for JSON logging, finer-grained control over what is logged. Fields can be
    ## retained or dropped, and request headers can be retained, dropped or redacted
    fields:
      # choices are keep, drop
      defaultMode: keep
      names: {}
        # ClientUsername: drop
      headers:
        # choices are keep, drop, redact
        defaultMode: keep
        names:
          "X-Forwarded-For": keep
          "X-Real-IP": keep
```

My access logs with this configuration look like the following though. No headers or X-Forwarded-For IP shown:

[image]

Comment: Are the targets in the target groups IP’s or Instances?

Comment: Layer 4 NLB is not HTTP aware, its just passing packets from host A to host B, so those HTTP headers don’t really exist. On an  NLB if the targets in you target group are IP’s you’ll need to implement `Proxy Protocol v2` on the NLB attributes screen in the console. If your targets are instances it will preserve the IP naturally.

Comment: @hephalump the targets on the classic LB are EC2 instances. Not seeing the X-Forwarded-For